# IPTables Limit port speed

Tags: iptables

I want to limit a port's speed down to 5 kb/s per client connected (trying to share out the limited connection without smashing the network)

I Have done research, mostly I find rules which drop connections upon to many attempts, this is not what I want.

I am rather new to IPTables and know the basics so maybe I have been googling the wrong question?
if any IPTable rules are posted could you please explain them in detail (what every part of the rule does) to help me further understand.

Answer (score 3):

I used the Traffic Control package and commands such as

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 netem delay 2ms
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: tbf rate 10mbit buffer 15000 limit 15000
```

I suggest you do a bit of googling as there are lots of resources out there such as http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/

Comment: Ok thank you, This is certainly a good starting point :)

Comment: Phil, are you sure that leading `up ` should be present on each line?  +1 from me for the `tc` idea, though; it's certainly the right tool, unlike `iptables`.

Comment: Ooops, those were the commands from my /etc/network/interfaces file to automatically do the throttling when the interfaces were brought up - I've updated the answer